# Laravel delete relationship and create new in one way?

Tags: laravel

Hi guys is it possible to do following code in one way?

```
    $Project->deadline()->delete();
    $Project->deadline()->create($deadline);
```

Project Model:

```
public function deadline()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserProjectDeadline','projects_id','id');
}
```

Comment: What error your getting ?

Comment: @SaschaK I don't think so. Still I might be wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Seems there's no methods for deleting and creating in one line of code, but Laravel offer functions `updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])` that can be used for hasOne relationships.

```
$Project->deadline()->updateOrCreate($attributes, $deadline); // To update based on the attributes
```

Or if you want to change/update all the data without any specified attributes

```
$Project->deadline()->updateOrCreate([], $deadline); // To update all the data
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a realy nice way if hasOne relationship is created in other step before. I thought There was something like sync, but with hasOne.

Comment: Should mark this as answer instead of upvote?